# Use puppeteer to select by text

Tags: javascript, forms, web-scraping, puppeteer

Working on a script that would use puppeteer to book tee times when they become available. If I have a specified day that I know I want to book, I was wondering if there's a good way to select that date in datepicker (all of the dates have a class "day" but aren't identifiable individually). This is datepicker **without an input**, on a site where I don't control the datepicker. I just want to be able to fill out the form and make the appropriate selections but all of the dates have the same selector. I'm attaching a picture of the datepicker. What is the best way to go about selecting a date that's 7 days in advance?

[image: datepicker calendar object]

Comment: can you share an example snippet of its HTML source as well (or the url of the page if it's public)?

Comment: it would be good to see if the current day has a unique class at least (I am sure it has one).

Comment: the selected day also has the class "selected"...and that starts on the current day by default...but other than that there's nothing that denotes which is the current day except that the preceding days are disabled.

Comment: The url is behind a membership wall...but I could share a snippet of the HTML (or a screenshot) if you could tell me which pieces would be helpful. @theDavidBarton

Comment: if the markup is not that massive amount it would be nice to see at least the element containing the month name, and: one past date, a selectable date element (e.g. 10th Sept) and the element with class `.selected`. most of the cases calendar elements can be iterated over with the same logic as they were created, that's why it is helpful to see how it is put into HTML (or if there's any other helpful properties like onclick events etc.)

Comment: You need to use xpath to select by text. Playwright can also do it it you feel like switching.

Comment: i agree that XPath's `contains()` is the most conveniant way to select an element based on its text content. but in case of a calendar component it is hard to use it to identify the dates. e.g. for _30th September 2020_ on this calendar it would select the first occurance of "30" which is an orphan day from August: _30th August 2020_. @toddmetheny could you align the title of your question to indicate it is about **non-input calendar date selection?** (selection by text is a slightly different topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In theory

You are able to collect the content of the calendar with `page.$eval` and `page.$$eval` methods:

```
const calMonthYear = await page.$eval('.calendar-monthname', month => month.innerText)
// September 2020

const calDays = await page.$$eval('.calendar-grid > ul > li', days => days.map(d => d.innerText))
// ["30", "31", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "1", "2", "3"]
```

*Note:* in the final example I declare them with `let` due to they need to be redeclared once we have to step to the next month on date selection.

Then if you concat the dates you can make every calendar day element a valid JavaScript Date object, e.g.:

```
Date.parse(`${calDays[10]} ${calMonthYear}`) // 9 September 2020
// 1599602400000
```

The current day (today) always has a specific class name, e.g.: `.selected`, we can evaluate its date with puppeteer (let's assume this is the valid "now" and not `Date.now()`)

```
const calToday = await page.$eval('.selected', day => day.innerText)
// 9
```

```
const todayIndex = calDays.indexOf(calToday)
// 10

const todayEpoch = Date.parse(`${calDays[todayIndex]} ${calMonthYear}`) // 9 September 2020
// 1599602400000
```

We can create a date desired to be selected in Epoch format (it should be `Date.parse()`-ed):

```
let today = new Date(todayEpoch)
let sevenDaysLater = new Date()
sevenDaysLater.setDate(today.getDate() + 7)
sevenDaysLater.setHours(0,0,0,0)
// 1600207200000  (Wed Sep 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time))
```

And finally you should compose an iteration to select the desired 7 days later element, something like this:

```
[...]

let calendarGridItemCount =  await page.$$eval('.calendar-grid > ul > li', el => el.length)
let calMonthYear = await page.$eval('.calendar-monthname', month => month.innerText)
let calDays = await page.$$eval('.calendar-grid > ul > li', days => days.map(d => d.innerText))

const wantedDate = Date.parse(sevenDaysLater)

  for (let i = 0; i < calendarGridItemCount; i++) {
    let examinedCalendarGridItem = Date.parse(`${calDays[i]} ${calMonthYear}`)
    if (examinedCalendarGridItem == wantedDate) {
      const dayFound = (await page.$$('.calendar-grid > ul > li'))[i]
      await dayFound.click()
      break
    } else if (examinedCalendarGridItem !== wantedDate && i === calendarGridItemCount - 1) {
      await page.click('.calendar-next')
      calendarGridItemCount = await page.$$eval('.calendar-grid > ul > li', el => el.length)
      calMonthYear = await page.$eval('.calendar-monthname', month => month.innerText)
      calDays = await page.$$eval('.calendar-grid > ul > li', days => days.map(d => d.innerText))
      i = 0
      continue
    }
  }
```

### Make sure:

- you handle those cases when the +7 days date is in the next month (step to the next month with the `.calendar-next` button);
- handling of the orphan days (either at the beginning of the month or at the end... if the orphans at the end are selectable, then it is not a problem) e.g.: you can clean the values of the orphans in `calDays` array with keeping their indexes (the indexes are needed in the iteration to identify the selectable dates, slicing the past dates would mess up their order).

Comment: Thanks David. Very helpful. The calendar doesn't have lists but table rows but the approach is really helpful. Going to try it ASAP.

Comment: yes, it should work with table <tr> <td>-s as well the same way. I wrote the script without running it so I made some mistakes that I fixed now. (1) don't forget to **parse the wantedDate** `const wantedDate = Date.parse(sevenDaysLater)` and (2) I made **syntax errors** in typing the `page.$eval`-s multiple times, now they are fixed also. I suggest to check my latest edits on the code.

Comment: have you been able to try it @toddmetheny?

Comment: Hey David--I haven't. That was for a personal project and I've had some other things come up and haven't gotten back to it yet. I can go ahead and approve, though, so I don't forget. Thanks for your help!